# delegate results of while loop, JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a while loop which counts from 175 to 255 in 20s i.e. 175, 215, 235, 255.
those results are stored in the variable `red` which is concatenated into a `background-color` property using jQuery.

```
    $(function(){
    var red=175;
    while  (red <= 235){
       red+=20; 
       console.log(red); 
    }

    $('.change').next().css({"backgroundColor":"rgb("+red+",255,50)"})

    });
```

When I console.log `red` it logs all four numbers mentioned above. when red is concatenated into the `backgroundColor` value it uses only the final number returned. My question is, is there a way I could delegate the four separate results into the `backgroundColor` values of four consecutive `<divs>` with the same class?

http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/HtpIC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var red = 175; //set the initial value for your variable
    $('.change').css('background-color', function () { //use the call back function of css to return the value
      return "rgb(" + (red += 20) + ",255,50)";  //return the rgb along with incrementing for the next element
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nejZT/

In your current code, what you are doing is that incrementing the value of the variable till your condition, so in the end you will have the value`of the variable as 235, and after that you are applying it to all of the but the first one with your statement

`$('.change').next().css({"backgroundColor":"rgb("+red+",255,50)"})`

Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for .css with function argument.

Not sure if you have a significance for the check <=235 if you want to repeat the cycle after it reaches the limit you can try this too.

```
$(function () {
    var red = 155;
    $('.change').css('background-color', function () {
        return "rgb(" + (red = ((red < 235) ? red + 20 : 175)) + ",255,50)";
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, this is much easier than the way I was trying to do it.

Comment: @BryanK You are welcome. DO you have any significance for the check `red <= 235`?

Comment: just so the loop would end at 255. which is the end of rgb color scale

Comment: Yeah thats there. i thought you want to repeat the cycle for other elements. like this http://jsfiddle.net/rUx9V/

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  Loop through your matching divs and increment their red color.  If, for some reason, you have more than 4 matching elements, this will not break, either.  It'll just apply a red val of 255 to elements 4+

```
var red = 175; // First matching element has a red val of 175
$('.change').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(' + red + ',255,50)');
    if (red <= 235) red += 20; // Only increment red if it's <= 235
});
```

Fiddle showing 6 divs (not breaking): http://jsfiddle.net/xwT5r/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$(function(){
    var red=175;
    var currElem = $(".change").first();
    while  (red <= 235){
       red+=20; 
       console.log(red); 
       currElem.css({"backgroundColor":"rgb("+red+",255,50)"});
       currElem = currElem.next(".change");
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QufM4/